# Postgres sql for Min Value

Tags: sql, postgresql, min

i have a postgres table like this:

```
|      val_date       |val_io_id|val_value|
2021-12-30 03:20:00+02  9224    30,3    
2021-12-30 11:10:00+02  9224    36,9
2021-12-30 11:35:00+02  9226    2,2
2021-12-30 12:50:00+02  6645    983
2021-12-30 11:20:00+02  3884    373
2021-12-30 12:45:00+02  3464    4,05
2021-12-30 15:50:00+02  9224    3912580
2021-12-30 17:45:00+02  5296    10,1
```

the only way i can makeit work is like this ... but i lose time part of occur from val_date

```
SELECT date(val_date), min(val_value)
FROM   data_store.vals_1
                WHERE val_io_id=9224 and date(val_date)='2021-12-30'
                Group BY date(val_date)
```

I want to extract min of (val_value) and datetime of occurr (val_date) for a val_io_id
i want result like this:

```
|      val_date       |val_io_id|val_value|
2021-12-30 03:20:00+02  9224    30,3
```

thanks

Comment: GROUP BY val_io_id instead.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
cte as 
(
select val_date,val_io_id,val_value, row_number()over(partition by val_io_id
order by val_value asc) as rnnmbur from data_store.vals_1
) select val_date,val_io_id,val_value where rnnmbur=1
```

another way in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (val_io_id), val_date,val_value
FROM data_store.vals_1 a

ORDER BY a.val_value sac
```